# Windows batch file to hold till required time?

Tags: batch-file, time

I have to hold my process till the SPECIFIED TIME reaches. To run the process, i have an option to run a pre-command in that software (i.e. a backup software having a feature to use pre-commands)

I am pushing a batch file as a pre-command to hold my process with this one:

```
set "currentTime=%Time: =0%"
set flag=false 
:COMPARE_TIME if %currentTime% geq 03:00 if %currentTime% leq 04:45 set flag=true 
if %flag%==true ( 
    goto :eof
) else ( 
    goto :COMPARE_TIME
)
```

but this process is not working and it runs at any time.. even between 3 to 4:45 am and anyother time

Comment: This is awful! Using a "busy wait" loop is never a good idea (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)! I would suggest to use the windows scheduler for this task. Is it possible to just start your process at the desired time or do you actually have to "wait" inside your code?

Comment: I know its a dirty way to wait. I have a big stack of backup jobs to be queued and some of them have time restrictions. So I want to send them all in a queue and to check if the job time is falling in 3 am to 4:45 am, dont do the backup just wait.

Comment: can you find out the error in this code. I want to compare time if the time is between 3 to 4:45, exit this file, otherwise jump to comparison, any other logic in mind ?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have the whole function on one line and you can't use else statements, use two if statements.

Try it like this...

```
set "currentTime=%Time: =0%"
set flag=false 
 :COMPARE_TIME
 if %currentTime% GEQ 12:30 if %currentTime% LEQ 12:55 SET flag=true 
 if %flag%==true ( 
    goto :eof
    )   
 if %flag%==false (
    set "currentTime=%Time: =0%"
    goto :COMPARE_TIME
    )
```

Comment: Maybe not..i'll try again

Comment: I have tested the previous one, and its working too now. thanks!

Comment: The batch `IF` statement does support `ELSE` statements.

Comment: The logic is okay, but the file not stops even after the specified time  arrives.

Comment: Are you using the latest edit of my answer? You need to make sure your function doesn't have any line breaks.

Comment: Well, i tried, the problem is when the time is within the specified, code works, and if that time is out of specified time, it gets on hold but stays on hold even if the specified time arrives!! so not working in this case

Comment: Ah yes I see now - you need to update the time variable if the match isnt successful! I have updated my answer.

Comment: so I have to move :COMPARE_TIME label at set currentTime

Comment: No, you just need the 'set "currentTime=%Time: =0%' line within the %flag%==false if statement.